# add a custom directive from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I know that Controller should not add HTML, and it's directive jobs. Unfortunatly, I can't manage it currently.

Here is what I do. submit() is call from template, I'm ashamed because I know i did it the wrong way :

```
/*in my Controller */       

    $scope.widget = widget;
    $scope.ContentList =['array','graph','nevermind']
    $scope.form = {
        name: widget.name,
        id: widget.id,
        content: widget.content
    };

 $scope.submit = function() {
    angular.extend(widget, $scope.form);
    $modalInstance.close(widget);

    $timeout(function(){$scope.ajouterDirective();},100); //THIS SUCK HARD !
};

$scope.ajouterDirective = function(){
    var idWid = $scope.widget.id;
    var directive = getDirectiveHtmlCode($scope.widget.content); // return sth like '<my-custom-directive></my-custom-directive>'
    var compiled = $compile(directive)($scope);
    $('#widget'+idWid).append(compiled); // this suck two
}
```

Can somebody tell me / give a link , which explain how to do it correctly plz?

Thank

---Edit-- 
The template for the form (very simplified)

```
<form name="_form" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="submit(_form)">
 Name: <input name="name" type="text" ng-model="form.name" class="form-control" />
Content : <select name="content" ng-model="form.content" class="form-control">
<option ng-repeat="value in ContentList" value="{{value}}">{{value}}</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: What do you want your user to provide in the form ?

Comment: he provide content depending on a  `<select></select>`

Comment: So you actually give a choice between a determined list of widget right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for something like this :

HTML :

```
  <input type="text" ng-model="widgetCustomName">
  <select ng-model="widgetName" ng-options="widget.directiveName as widget.name for widget in widgets">
  </select>
  <button ng-click="addWidget()">Add directive</button>

  <!--  I'll repeat for each widgets placed by the user  -->
  <div ng-repeat="widget in placedWidgets">
    <h2>{{widget.customName}}</h2>
    <!--  here i'll use the directive according to the widget technical name -->
    <div ng-switch on="widget.widget">
      <mywidget1 ng-switch-when="mywidget1">Widget1</mywidget1>
      <mywidget2 ng-switch-when="mywidget2">Widget2</mywidget2>
      <div ng-switch-default>Crap you didn't select a widget</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Controller :

```
//We will look through this collection to display our widgets
$scope.placedWidgets = [];
//We define here the widgets availables in the select. name is a display name and directiveName the name of the associated directive.
$scope.widgets = [{
  "name" : "Widget1",
  "directiveName" : "mywidget1"
},{
  "name" : "Widget2",
  "directiveName" : "mywidget2"
}]

//This will be the function adding a widget in the collection according to the user inputs.
$scope.addWidget = function(){
  $scope.placedWidgets.push({
    "customName":$scope.widgetCustomName,
    "widget":$scope.widgetName
  })
}
```

Here is the associated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pBNpSgXvhCO4fJ4saT7N?p=preview).
I hope the comments will be enough as explanation but if you need more informations just feel free to ask.

Comment: It look nice. Thinqs for the ng-option on the select and the ng-switch.
I wonder : How it understand that '<mywidget1>' is like a <p> ? Just a browser default behaviour/ angular default behavour?

Comment: @ssbb Actually the brother thinks that "<mywidget1>" isn't a valid HTML tag. Then he will just do nothing special. The text is just show as you can place text everywhere (not only in <p>). If your angular app have a mywidget1 directive, it will replace (or not, depending on your directive definition) this tag with the widget content.